# Using Google Drive drive.appfolder scope for saving app backup

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api

I have an app for which I am trying to create data backup & restore functionality where if user want, he can store backup on google drive. If he uninstalls the app and re-installs the app on same or different device then we can restore the backup from Drive.

Can I use Google Drive drive.appfolder scope for this purpose? If yes, what is the limitation?

Comment: You could.  The only thing is i am not sure if the directory will be deleted when the app is uninstalled you will need to test that.

Comment: Yes, that is my concern.
Actually I have implemented the backup and restoring using drive.file scope, but as this is a restricted scope, in-order to use the app in a production environment verification from google is required, and that is a problem.

Comment: Well if you use drive scope its going to have to be verified as well. anything that will give you access to write to a users account is.

Comment: @DalmTo  Yes. That's why I am looking for an alternate solution :)